# facebook disabled - Ineligible

Tags: facebook

i tried to log in to my facebook and it says:" Your account was disabled because we determined that you are ineligible to use Facebook. For more information about our policies, please review the Facebook Terms. If you think your account was disabled by mistake, please contact us." When i tried to go to "contact us" it says: "We could not process your request. Please try again later."
What should i do? i don't know why my account is deleted or deactiveted, i don't have any "warn" e mail. I really need my acc. back, i have a lots of stuff there. Please, help me
(p.s sorry for bad english, i'm from serbia)

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Stack Overflow is for questions about a real, actual programming problem you're facing as a developer. For Facebook support, please see [Facebook's Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/). Good luck!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

regaining your Facebook account is not simple, as this involves knowing their Terms of Services. Be polite when contacting them. For more tips and Facebook contact information, see facebookblockedaccount.com/.

but you can try this:

1. use your signed e-mail for facebook
2. write FB email with subject = complain
3. Contact them from the homepage of facebook.com

they may answer you and see the problem with your account, but not 100% as i mention before.